# My project cant see send or received messages

Tags: android, android-activity

It keeps crashing at one point on 2 Activities:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityUtilities.customiseActionBar(this);

}
```

My `ActivityUtilities.customiseActionBar` leads to:

```
public class ActivityUtilities {

    public static void customiseActionBar(Activity activity)
    {
        int titleId = 0;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            titleId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        else
            titleId = R.id.action_bar_title;

        if(titleId>0){
            TextView titleView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(titleId);
            titleView.setTextSize(22);
        }
    }

}
```

The error code I'm getting is:

```
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ajapps.app, PID: 17854
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ajapps.app/com.ajapps.app.Wifichat.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextSize(float)' on a null object reference
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextSize(float)' on a null object reference
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ajapps.app.Wifichat.util.ActivityUtilities.customiseActionBar(ActivityUtilities.java:23)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ajapps.app.Wifichat.Login.onPostCreate(Login.java:95)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1201)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3101)
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218) 
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198) 
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676) 
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837) 
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
11-01 16:19:40.991 17854-17854/com.ajapps.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

If I remove `ActivityUtilities.customiseActionBar`, it works fine but my app won't receive any message.

Chatactivity:

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "ChatActivity";   
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int TAKE_PHOTO = 2;
private static final int RECORD_AUDIO = 3;
private static final int RECORD_VIDEO = 4;
private static final int CHOOSE_FILE = 5;
private static final int DRAWING = 6;
private static final int DOWNLOAD_IMAGE = 100;
private static final int DELETE_MESSAGE = 101;
private static final int DOWNLOAD_FILE = 102;
private static final int COPY_TEXT = 103;
private static final int SHARE_TEXT = 104;

private WifiP2pManager mManager;
private Channel mChannel;
private WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
private EditText edit;
private static ListView listView;
private static List<Message> listMessage;
private static ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
private Uri fileUri;
private String fileURL;
private ArrayList<Uri> tmpFilesUri;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
    mReceiver = WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver.createInstance();
    mReceiver.setmActivity(this);

    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    //Start the service to receive message
    startService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class));

    //Initialize the adapter for the chat
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageList);
    listMessage = new ArrayList<Message>();
    chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this, listMessage);
    listView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

    //Initialize the list of temporary files URI
    tmpFilesUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();

    //Send a message
    AddFloatingActionButton button = (AddFloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMessage);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(!edit.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Log.v(TAG, "Send message");
                sendMessage(Message.TEXT_MESSAGE);
            }               
            else{
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Please enter a not empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    //Register the context menu to the list view (for pop up menu)
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivityUtilities.customiseActionBar(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);        

    mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.v(TAG, "Discovery process succeeded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Discovery process failed");
        }
    });
    saveStateForeground(true);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    saveStateForeground(false);
}    

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    newDialog.setTitle("Close chatroom");
    newDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this chatroom?\n"
            + "You will no longer be able to receive messages, and "
            + "all unsaved media files will be deleted.\n"
            + "If you are the host, all other users will be disconnected as well.");

    newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            clearTmpFiles(getExternalFilesDir(null));
            if(Login.server!=null){
                Login.server.interrupt();
            }       
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); 
        }

    });

    newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    newDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onStop();
    clearTmpFiles(getExternalFilesDir(null));
}

// Handle the data sent back by the 'for result' activities (pick/take image, record audio/video)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode){
        case PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null) {
                fileUri = data.getData();
                sendMessage(Message.IMAGE_MESSAGE);                 
            }
            break;
        case TAKE_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null) {
                fileUri = data.getData();
                sendMessage(Message.IMAGE_MESSAGE);
                tmpFilesUri.add(fileUri);
            }
            break;
        case RECORD_AUDIO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                fileURL = (String) data.getStringExtra("audioPath");
                sendMessage(Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE);
            }
            break;
        case RECORD_VIDEO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                fileUri = data.getData();
                fileURL = MediaFile.getRealPathFromURI(this, fileUri);
                sendMessage(Message.VIDEO_MESSAGE);
            }
            break;
        case CHOOSE_FILE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                fileURL = (String) data.getStringExtra("filePath");
                sendMessage(Message.FILE_MESSAGE);
            }
            break;
        case DRAWING:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                fileURL = (String) data.getStringExtra("drawingPath");
                sendMessage(Message.DRAWING_MESSAGE);
            }
            break;
    }
}

// Hydrate Message object then launch the AsyncTasks to send it
public void sendMessage(int type){
    Log.v(TAG, "Send message starts");
    // Message written in EditText is always sent
    Message mes = new Message(type, edit.getText().toString(), null, Login.chatName);

    switch(type){
        case Message.IMAGE_MESSAGE:
            Image image = new Image(this, fileUri);
            Log.v(TAG, "Bitmap from url ok");
            mes.setByteArray(image.bitmapToByteArray(image.getBitmapFromUri()));                
            mes.setFileName(image.getFileName());
            mes.setFileSize(image.getFileSize());               
            Log.v(TAG, "Set byte array to image ok");
            break;
        case Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE:
            MediaFile audioFile = new MediaFile(this, fileURL, Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE);
            mes.setByteArray(audioFile.fileToByteArray());
            mes.setFileName(audioFile.getFileName());
            mes.setFilePath(audioFile.getFilePath());
            break;
        case Message.VIDEO_MESSAGE:
            MediaFile videoFile = new MediaFile(this, fileURL, Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE);
            mes.setByteArray(videoFile.fileToByteArray());
            mes.setFileName(videoFile.getFileName());
            mes.setFilePath(videoFile.getFilePath());
            tmpFilesUri.add(fileUri);
            break;
        case Message.FILE_MESSAGE:
            MediaFile file = new MediaFile(this, fileURL, Message.FILE_MESSAGE);
            mes.setByteArray(file.fileToByteArray());
            mes.setFileName(file.getFileName());
            break;
        case Message.DRAWING_MESSAGE:
            MediaFile drawingFile = new MediaFile(this, fileURL, Message.DRAWING_MESSAGE);
            mes.setByteArray(drawingFile.fileToByteArray());
            mes.setFileName(drawingFile.getFileName());
            mes.setFilePath(drawingFile.getFilePath());
            break;
    }       
    Log.v(TAG, "Message object hydrated");

    Log.v(TAG, "Start AsyncTasks to send the message");
    if(mReceiver.isGroupeOwner() == WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver.IS_OWNER){
        Log.v(TAG, "Message hydrated, start SendMessageServer AsyncTask");
        new SendMessageServer(ChatActivity.this, true).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mes);
    }
    else if(mReceiver.isGroupeOwner() == WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver.IS_CLIENT){
        Log.v(TAG, "Message hydrated, start SendMessageClient AsyncTask");
        new SendMessageClient(ChatActivity.this, mReceiver.getOwnerAddr()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mes);
    }       

    edit.setText("");
}

// Refresh the message list
public static void refreshList(Message message, boolean isMine){
    Log.v(TAG, "Refresh message list starts");

    message.setMine(isMine);

    listMessage.add(message);
    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Log.v(TAG, "Chat Adapter notified of the changes");

    //Scroll to the last element of the list
    listView.setSelection(listMessage.size() - 1);
}   

// Save the app's state (foreground or background) to a SharedPrefereces
public void saveStateForeground(boolean isForeground){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("isForeground", isForeground);
    edit.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat, menu);
    return true;
}

// Handle click on the menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int idItem = item.getItemId();
    switch(idItem){
        case R.id.send_image:
            showPopup(edit);
            return true;

        case R.id.send_audio:
            Log.v(TAG, "Start activity to record audio");
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, RecordAudioActivity.class), RECORD_AUDIO);
            return true;

        case R.id.send_video:
            Log.v(TAG, "Start activity to record video");
            Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
            if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, RECORD_VIDEO);
            }
            return true;

        case R.id.send_file:
            Log.v(TAG, "Start activity to choose file");
            Intent chooseFileIntent = new Intent(this, FilePickerActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(chooseFileIntent, CHOOSE_FILE);
            return true;

        case R.id.send_drawing:
            Log.v(TAG, "Start activity to draw");
            Intent drawIntent = new Intent(this, DrawingActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(drawIntent, DRAWING);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);           
    }  
}   

//Show the popup menu
public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.pick_image:
                Log.v(TAG, "Pick an image");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                // Prevent crash if no app can handle the intent
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.take_photo:
                Log.v(TAG, "Take a photo");
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                if (intent2.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent2, TAKE_PHOTO);
                }                   
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.inflate(R.menu.send_image);
    popup.show();
}

//Create pop up menu for image download, delete message, etc...
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    Message mes = listMessage.get((int) info.position);

    //Option to delete message independently of its type
    menu.add(0, DELETE_MESSAGE, Menu.NONE, "Delete message");

    if(!mes.getmText().equals("")){
        //Option to copy message's text to clipboard
        menu.add(0, COPY_TEXT, Menu.NONE, "Copy message text");
        //Option to share message's text
        menu.add(0, SHARE_TEXT, Menu.NONE, "Share message text");
    }        

    int type = mes.getmType();
    switch(type){
        case Message.IMAGE_MESSAGE:
            menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_IMAGE, Menu.NONE, "Download image");
            break;
        case Message.FILE_MESSAGE:
            menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_FILE, Menu.NONE, "Download file");
            break;
        case Message.AUDIO_MESSAGE:
            menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_FILE, Menu.NONE, "Download audio file");
            break;
        case Message.VIDEO_MESSAGE:
            menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_FILE, Menu.NONE, "Download video file");
            break;
        case Message.DRAWING_MESSAGE:
            menu.add(0, DOWNLOAD_FILE, Menu.NONE, "Download drawing");
            break;
    }
}

//Handle click event on the pop up menu
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DOWNLOAD_IMAGE:
            downloadImage(info.id);
            return true;

        case DELETE_MESSAGE:
            deleteMessage(info.id);
            return true;

        case DOWNLOAD_FILE:
            downloadFile(info.id);
            return true;

        case COPY_TEXT:
            copyTextToClipboard(info.id);
            return true;

        case SHARE_TEXT:
            shareMedia(info.id, Message.TEXT_MESSAGE);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//Download image and save it to Downloads
public void downloadImage(long id){  
    Message mes = listMessage.get((int) id);
    Bitmap bm = mes.byteArrayToBitmap(mes.getByteArray());      
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();

    FileUtilities.saveImageFromBitmap(this, bm, path, mes.getFileName());
    FileUtilities.refreshMediaLibrary(this);
}

//Download file and save it to Downloads
public void downloadFile(long id){
    Message mes = listMessage.get((int) id);
    String sourcePath = mes.getFilePath();
    String destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();

    FileUtilities.copyFile(this, sourcePath, destinationPath, mes.getFileName());
    FileUtilities.refreshMediaLibrary(this);
}

//Delete a message from the message list (doesn't delete on other phones)
public void deleteMessage(long id){
    listMessage.remove((int) id);
    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void clearTmpFiles(File dir){
    File[] childDirs = dir.listFiles(); 
    for(File child : childDirs){
        if(child.isDirectory()){
            clearTmpFiles(child);
        }
        else{
            child.delete();
        }
    }
    for(Uri uri: tmpFilesUri){
        getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
    }
    FileUtilities.refreshMediaLibrary(this);
}

public void talkTo(String destination){
    edit.setText("@" + destination + " : ");
    edit.setSelection(edit.getText().length());
}

private void copyTextToClipboard(long id){
    Message mes = listMessage.get((int) id);
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("message", mes.getmText());
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Message copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void shareMedia(long id, int type){
    Message mes = listMessage.get((int) id);

    switch(type){
        case Message.TEXT_MESSAGE:
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mes.getmText());
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: titleView doesn't get created inside postCreate method. Android Make sure it will get created and present in view hierarchy on onCreate call back

Comment: Do you have a example please?

Comment: I would suggest move all those logic of onPostCreate --> inside onStart method

Comment: @dex Your idea worked but I still can't view send or received messages. Any idea's?

Comment: which type of message you are trying to send, can you please post that code also.

Comment: Ive updated it for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That hasn't helps unfortunately @Henry

Comment: @AJ-Apps : can you please tell describe how you are sending message and how you wanted to view that message...I am going through your code but its too large (sorry).

Answer (score 0):

can you try below code

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleId)
```